# How can I get the email associated to an Instagram username?

Tags: android, email, instagram

I am building an application, and I would like to know if there is some way to get the Instagram username associated to a email. In my application people log in with their email. I would like to get their Instagram account so I can see their "influence".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to retrieve the email address as this would pose a potential security risk/privacy issue.